# How to post values for checkboxes with ng-model?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have two checkboxes in the form now user can select one or both and post the data to server, But i am not sure,how i will bind both values to `$scope.ng-model` when user post the data ?

main.html

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-value="'uploadPrc'" ng-model="prcModel">Upload PRC
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-value="'uploadPrt'" ng-model="prtModel">Upload PRT
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angulars "two way data binding" works like this:
Initialize your form data on the controller scope

```
$scope.form = {
  prcModel: false,
  prtModel: false
}
```

And in your view:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-value="'form.prcModel'" ng-model="form.prcModel">Upload PRC
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-value="'form.prtModel'" ng-model="form.prtModel">Upload PRT
    </label>
</div>
```

If you change the value of your checkboxes the value of your model will instantly change as well.
So all you need to do is deal with your `$scope.form` in your controller.

Comment: so if i post the data for form.prcModel, what value will be sent to server in above example ?

Comment: if for example your PRC checkbox  is checked `$scope.form.prcModel` will be `true` and that value is going to be posted.

Comment: in that case i should keep ng-model same for both checkboxes

Comment: and another thing is confusing me, is it necessary to keep ng-value and ng-model same ?

Comment: thank you i figured it out and its working good. Thank you stack its great help!

Answer (score 0):

Don´t know if is this what you are looking for, but why not try have your own model like:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myModel.prcModel">Upload PRC
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myModel.prtModel">Upload PRT
    </label>
</div>
```

so in .js code you can send and receive the model "myModel" as an object and the values will be true or false

```
...
var data = $scope.myModel
...
$scope.myModel = data;
```